# Prefix headers in other IDEs than Xcode

Tags: c, visual-studio, c++11, compilation, qt-creator

The prefix header functionality in Xcode comes in handy quite often and I was wondering if other IDEs provide a similar functionality? Or is there even a way on compiler level?

I've been looking for this in other environments for quite a time and the only thing I could find were precompiled headers. But that's not really the same as you still need to include the header file in each source file.

So, does anyone know if there's a way to configure prefix headers in IDEs like Visual Studio or QT Creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VC++ you can specify [`Forced Include File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx) using option /FI on command line or through an IDE. An excerpt from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx):

> **To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development
>   environment:**
>       1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. 
>       2. Click the C/C++ folder.
>       3. Click the Advanced property page.
>       4. Modify the Force Includes property.

Comment: Thanks, force include header was the keyword I had to search for

Answer (score 0):

For QtCreator you can add two lines to your *.pro file:

`CONFIG += precompile_header`

`PRECOMPILED_HEADER = stdafx.h`

Of course, you can type any name instead of "stdafx.h"

Comment: As I've already written, precompiled and prefix header is not the same thing. But you can do it in Qt by adding "-include YourHeader.h" to the QMAKE_CXXFLAGS setting.